# Ubuntu SFTP file uploads get disconnected?

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I have a few servers running Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS, and they have all had an intermittent problem with uploading files from my Windows development machine. Occasionally when an upload is started (via SFTP) the upload starts in the client, the file is created server side, then it times out. The file on the server remains at 0kb. It can be deleted or overwritten, but once this has occurred once, each subsequent file upload results in the same problem for a period of time, sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes hours. Downloads work normally. File size doesn't seem to matter (1kb or 50mb), different SFTP clients result in the same error. Pulling my hair out over this one, and all my searching has not turned up an answer.

**Update:** Using PHPStorm, I am still running into this same issue, but it gives a little more information. The upload progress bar completes, it spins for a while, then it says:

```
Failed to transfer file 'filename.ext': could not close the output stream for file "sftp://host.tld/filename.ext".
```

I tried turning off the firewall on the server, thinking maybe it was getting in the way (`sudo ufm disable`) to no effect.

**Update 2 (2014-07-29)** I have found that if I connect to an encrypted VPN, I never have this issue, and it fixes the issue if I enable it after having problems without it. This leads me to think that this is somehow connected to my ISP? Is this at all a possibility? The only difference in the traffic is that it is encrypted to the VPN source, which is NOT internal to the server (so the server is still seeing it as external traffic).

Comment: Does this windows system communicate with these servers in any way besides SFTP? Do you see the problem with any other programs? In particular, can you make an interactive SSH session from the PC to these servers without any trouble?

Comment: Yes, I can connect via SSH and HTTP/S just fine to the server during this time. It doesn't seem to matter what SFTP client I use, they all encounter the error.

Comment: So it's not something like a routing problem or IP address conflict. And SFTP traffic runs through an encrypted SSH pipe. So a firewall couldn't selectively allow SSH while blocking SFTP. Maybe something is blocking the disk writes? Are these servers running virus scanners?

Comment: The one I'm currently having an issue with (I've had the issue with a lof of different servers over time) is a pretty standard Ubuntu Server headless install, with Apache, MySQL, PHP. I haven't set up any virus scanners or anything.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is to inspect the server process handling the SFTP session. OpenSSH normally runs a program named "sftp-server" to handle SFTP sessions. Use your client to open an SFTP session to the server. On the server, find the sftp-server instance and run `strace -p pid-of-sftp-server`. Strace will start printing the system calls made by the program being traced. Then try to upload a file from the client. You should be able to see the system calls where sftp-server receives the command from the client, creates the target file, and tries to write to it.

Comment: When I start `strace` with the PID of `sftp-server`, it says `$ sudo strace -p 1808
[sudo] password for :
Process 1808 attached - interrupt to quit
select(2, [0], [], NULL, NULL`, and when I try to upload a file, nothing happens.

Comment: Okay, maybe your client session is being blocked soon after starting. Maybe you have some overzealous antivirus on your PC? Maybe repeat the previous test, but run tcpdump on the _server_ to see if any packets are arriving when you try to start an upload?

Comment: Currently uploads are working again... The problem is intermittent. I'll have to wait until it stops working again before I can debug some more.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like wireshark to see what packets are being generated and sent in both directions. Get to the lowest level you can and see what's actually happening.

Comment: I've never used wireshark, can that be used on a headless server?

Comment: If you have a desktop environment installed and use VNC, yes. If you use the terminal only you can use `tcpdump` to monitor packets.

Comment: I used Wireshark on my client end to capture the port 22 traffic during a failed upload, however, I have no idea what it means...

Answer (score 0):

I'd check free disk space on the server or your user quota.

I'd expect some error message in this case, not timeout, but other indices indicate lack of disk space.

Comment: I've checked, and free space / disk quotas are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your anti-virus software temporarily. I had this problem and disabling AVG 2014 allowed the uploads to proceed per normal from my dev PC to the server.

This could also be caused by Windows Defender and AVG trying to scan the same data stream at once if you have Windows 8, although I can't confirm the hypothesis.

Comment: I use NOD32 on Windows 7. However, I've updated the question with some more details that I have discovered.

Comment: Have you tried disabling NOD32 temporarily to see? I don't believe antivirus software can scan a secure stream, so that may in fact be taking it out of the loop.